# How to solve opacity issue on mouseenter and mouselieave from a menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have a menu on the top of a page, I need an overlay at the background with black color and and `opacity = 0.7`, this "overlay" has to appear at `li:hover` (`mouseenter`) and disappear at `mouseleave`. This is what I've done so far [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lavi/PERf7/1/) and this is the [fullscreen result](http://jsfiddle.net/lavi/PERf7/embedded/result/)

What I got:

1. `mousenter` works well.
2. `mouseleave` issue, the overlay appears and disappear everytime the mouse leave (it seems a party flashing div), I know is logic, but what can I do?

If I comment some lines in the code I see what I want but the overlay stays visible.

```
function iniciarmenu() {
    $(".menu-links ul li").hover(

    function () {
        $(".overlay").animate({
            opacity: 0.7
        }, 'fast');
    },

    function () {
        /*$(".overlay").animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 'fast');*/
    });
}
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: So are you asking for it not to fade out and become dark again if you're going directly to another button in the menu?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy yes something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to stop the current animation first.

```
 $(".overlay").stop( true, true ).animate( { … } );
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

You could also use CSS to achieve that effect:

```
.overlay:hover {
    opacity: .7;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
       -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
         -o-transition: opacity .2s;
            transition: opacity .2s;
}
```

Comment: +1 for adding CSS solution. Why .stop( true, true ) and not just .stop() ?

Comment: I was just thinking CSS might be the solution to this, and then there's this answer that covers both. Nice job.

Comment: @miro: it ends the current animation immediately, instead of at the end of an animation cycle: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Thanks! I was just looking into it too. Here's an interesting demo: http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/
 stop(true, false); is good too.

Comment: I tried something else, `$(".overlay").stop( true, false ).animate( { … } );` Thanks for your answer.